# Help to improve my video

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have produced a short video but I'm not really enjoyed of it. Images are quite blurry and it is not nice to watch. When the camera move, we can kind of sparkles.

Would you have advise to improve it ? Would you have reasons for this poor quality ?

This is the video  : https://youtu.be/NQD0zOMuNmY

This the parameter of the animation : 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of your blurring is coming from the denoising post-process.

firstly, make sure motion blur is not turned on.

To avoid blurriness from the denoising, you have to increase your sampling.

256 or 512 should do it,. but will take a lot longer to render.

Alternatively, try using Blender 2.8 and use the EEVEE renderer. It is so much faster - and your scene doesnt require any complex light paths, so it should work really well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for  your advise ! Motion blur is not turned on and my sampling is already at 600 ... Would you have another idea ?

Comment: Well, you could try a full HD render. set the image size to 1920 x 1080, and export to PNG. PNG s lossless, so it will produce very high quality source.

Then create your video from the PNGs. There are loads of free apps that will do this for you - but I can't advise which one. I use Adobe Media Encoder.
But I think you will get better results with EEVEE in Blender 2.8 - it is so much faster.

Comment: No worries! Let me know if it helped